# Can one implement AES on 4-bit microcontroller?

Tags: aes, implementation, lightweight

It is possible to implement AES on 4-bit microcontroller? As far as I know, AES on 8-bit microcontroller are common especially for light weight application such as the RFID.

I have yet to come across AES been employed on 4-bit microcontroller, therefore I have been wondering whether such implementation is feasible.

Comment: Using two 4 bit data structures you can construct an 8 bit data structure. So in that manner it is definitely possible to put AES on a 4-bit microcontroller.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: it would be similar to multiple precision integer arithmetic (see http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf for details).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, AES could be implemented on a 4-bit micro-controller such as this [EM6626](http://www.emmicroelectronic.com/Products.asp?IdProduct=179), and that would not be rocket science or stupidly slow. This [application note](http://www.emmicroelectronic.com/webfiles/Product/MCU/an/AN30.pdf) illustrates that all kind of 8-bit operations are simple, and table lookups are possible.

In fact, tables are not even indispensable if performance is non-critical; see this [minimalist AES source code in C](http://www.literatecode.com/aes256) which has a compilation option to avoid any table.

The most serious issue is the amount of RAM required: current 128-bit subkey and 128-bit data will eat half of the total 512-bit RAM of the above device.

Also worrying is the security: I know no 4-bit micro-controller with any kind of security evaluation. Thus I would trust such an implementation only if it is operated in a secure environment, and with a key that vanishes from the device after use. That's an appropriate security model for an enciphering machine, but not a copy-protection dongle.

Comment: thanks for the information. by any chance that AES in the field of GF((2^4)^2) would be efficient for 4-bit MCU in comparison to the AES in the field of GF((2^2)^4) and GF(((2^2)^2)^2)?

Answer (score 12):

The paper [Enabling Standardized Cryptography on Ultra-Constrained 4-bit Microcontrollers](http://www.uclouvain.be/crypto/ecrypt_lc11/static/post_proceedings.pdf) (page 255) describes such an implementation.

Comment: That's a good reading there... With a practical approach..